# What exactly IS the review queue?

Tags: support

I have been told that I have earned the privilege to access review queues, but not what that is. The announcement does not *link* the way new badges do. I have poked around but should be grateful for a "Review Queues for Dummies", if someone would take pity on a poor newbie. Strangely enough, it's not on "Questions that may already have an answer" (as opposed to questions about the details of RQs, including some nigh-flamewars), so perhaps I have now earned the Idiot badge..... Anyway, I have no intention of going near a RQ until I know what I am supposed to be doing. I may be dim tonight (blame the tropics), but I'm not a vandal or a troll.

Comment: Do you see a number inside an orange box up on your menu bar? Click on it to get to the review queue.

Comment: No I don't, Kit, but I do see a clickable link hight "Review". I have in fact been there, but am lacking an overview of general principles. As a promotee, what is expected of me – and not? (Remember the Peter Principle.)

Comment: @KitZ.Fox you don't see the orange box of available review notifcations until 10k rep ([Notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/213963) - "As of a few minutes ago, we are replacing the pending suggested edit count in the top bar with the number of pending reviews for diamond moderators and folks with the "moderation tools" privilege (i.e. 10k users on graduated sites and whatever that level's at on betas)")

Comment: @KitZ.Fox For normal users only suggested edits show the orange box.

Comment: i'm absolutely astounded at the downvote on this question.  is this question too *dumb*?  no wonder people think we're unwelcoming.

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information about this privilege in the Privileges section of the Help Center. [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) is the link for the privilege you just received.

The queues provide a means by which users can help keep the site tidy. As you gain more privileges, you will be able to access more queues that will help you use your new privileges more effectively.

You have access to only two queues at this stage. It's explained in that post, but to recap, you can help review answers that were posted long after the question was asked (late answers) and first posts. Late answers are reviewed because they are often either spam or new users. First posts are reviewed because very often the first question or answer that a user posts is their worst one, and we want to make sure that the community helps those new users get started off on the right foot. Having these two queues available to you makes it easier for you to identify posts that might need editing or encouraging comments, or that might need to be flagged.

You are allowed to do reviews in these queues, but you are not required to. You can participate as much or as little as you like. You can earn badges from working the queues.

Comment: Thank you kindly, sir. That is precisely what I was looking for, I may be at fault for not finding it there. (But site might consider adding an automatic pop-up or something?) I owe you a virtual beer.

Comment: I'm still puzzled. I had my first look at the review queue just now, and the New User items had already been commented on by high-reppers. So what is the point of this again? I had thought it was a first pass, but it isn't.

Comment: @DavidPugh it won't always contain something for you to review.